# Can I SUBST a network drive?

Tags: windows, command-line, windows-server-2003

I have a network share mapped to drive `T:` and I want to be able to access if easily from a specific directory. However, entering `subst t: c:\volumes\test` gives the error message `Invalid parameter - T:`

Is there a limitation on mapped network drives or Windows server 2003, or am I doing something wrong?

**Update:**

As [EBGreen points out](https://superuser.com/a/389490/42113), I don't actually want to use subst, since it doesn't do what I thought it did. I'm coming from a Linux environment, where remote shares can be mounted on to a directory in the filesystem.

Is there something in Windows that'll let me do this?

Comment: subst does the exact opposite of what you are trying to do.

Comment: @Harry You're right. I haven't had to use it since about 1989 and its purpose had become somewhat confused in my mind over time.

Comment: In the interest of credit where credit is due, Synetech and Harry johnson had it right, I had it backwards.

Comment: @EBGreen, to be fair, if Kalessin’s avatar is at all representative, then English may not be their first language. `;-)`

Comment: No, any confusion was certainly my fault.

Comment: @EBGreen Given that English *is* my first language and I got subst usage backwards, I'll take the blame and walk away. Thanks for all your input anyway :)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that C: is an NTFS volume, what you want is to create either an [NTFS volume mount point](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc938934.aspx) or a [junction point](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/205524) depending on your needs.

You can use Disk Management (diskmgmt.msc) to mount T: as a directory in C: or from the command-line (replace the GUID with the one of the target drive):

```
> md C:\Volumes\Test
> mountvol C:\Volumes\Test \\?\Volume{GUID}\
```

Alternately, you can also use `mklink` to create a junction point:

```
> mklink /j C:\Volumes\Test T:\
```

Since `mklink` is not included in Server 2003 (`o.O`), [this shell-extension](http://schinagl.priv.at/nt/hardlinkshellext/hardlinkshellext.html) can be used to create and manage junction points.

Comment: I don't think either of these will work when T is a mapped network drive.  Junction points are (sadly) user-context-independent, and mapped network drives are per-user-context.

Comment: I couldn’t test because I don’t have any networked drives.

Comment: Mountvol lists possible values for the VolumeName parameter and drive T is not amongst them. I don't seem to have mklink available on my system, so I'll look into that... **Edit:** mklink is available only from Vista/Server 2008 onwards.

Comment: @Kalessin, then Harry is correct; it does not support network drives. I would have thought that `mklink` would be available in Server2003 (considering it is a server edition). Well, junction points are nevertheless supported, so you can use [this shell-extension](http://schinagl.priv.at/nt/hardlinkshellext/hardlinkshellext.html) (which should even make it easier to use).

Answer (score 0):

I have used `mklink` to do exactly this. You don't even need to map a drive letter.

Using your example try this:

```
mklink /d c:\volumes\test \\servername\share
```